# Add a shortcode above the WooCommerce product short description

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to add a shortcode to all my woocommerce single product pages. I want the shortcode to appear above the short description.

I have found this code and added it to functions.php, but I can see that it adds the shortcode below the short description (and above the add to cart button).

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
   $text = do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
  return $description.$text;
}
```

I would be very gratefull for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function customShortcodeBeforeShortDescription( $post_excerpt ) 
{
    echo do_shortcode('[wpqr-code]');    
}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','customShortcodeBeforeShortDescription', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. This did not work unfortunately.

Comment: change priorities and see, it will

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook. try the below code. The code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_shortcode_before_short_description(){
    echo do_shortcode( '[wpqr-code]' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_shortcode_before_short_description', 15, 1 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]